# 'Terminal unknown' is disturbing creation of previous picture

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am having a weird problem with plotting several pictures. So I use the following Perl-script to call gnuplot:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(GP, "| gnuplot >>gnuplot.log 2>&1") or die "Error: $!\n";
print GP << "GNU_EOF";

set terminal pdf
set output 'test.pdf'
plot 'data.log' u 1:2

set terminal unknown
plot 'data.log' u 1:2
replot 'data.log' u 1:3

set terminal pdf
set output 'testOverall.pdf'
replot

GNU_EOF
close(GP);
```

I use `terminal unknown` to draw several lines and after drawing the last one I define an output (and terminal) to actually write the pdf. This works but somehow this plotting to unknown is disturbing the previous plot (in my example **test.pdf**) which has zero size.

It is always the picture **before** the plotting to unknown. My dirty workaround is to plot some dummy picture between test.pdf and testOverall.pdf and remove that zero sized dummy after calling gnuplot...

Why is this happening and how can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need to plot the lines to unknown? Also, you hanven't changed the output, so the output from the unknown terminal still goes to the `test.pdf`.

Comment: @choroba I do plot to unknown terminal because I don't wanna actually write the image. I first add several lines using *replot*. Afterwards I define **terminal pdf** and specify an output. My script is just a minimal example of my real script.

Comment: No, you specified output before, then set terminal and plot. It still goes to the old output. Try unsetting the output. I still don't understand why you need to plot the lines at all.

Comment: @choroba You are right! Write that as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify a terminal and output for the first image. You then change the terminal, but the output stays the same - therefore, the "several lines" go to the first pdf file. Try unsetting the output before drawing them.